# Android Studio running app with compile time errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

*Today i am having a weird issue with Android Studio IDE.*

You can see i did not add dependency of `RecyclerView` and `Support-v4`, and classes are showing errors. Now its fine. But issue is i am able to run project, my app is running in mobile, gradle does not show errors about the classes with error.

I don't expect this behavior of Android Studio.

[image]

*You can see I did not add `RecyclerView` dependency.*

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':Baselib')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${RETROFIT_VER}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${RETROFIT_VER}"
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VER"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VER"
    implementation "com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation "com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.tencent.mm.opensdk:wechat-sdk-android-without-mta:+'
}
```

*Now see magic of Android Studio*

[image]

Is this a new feature of Android Studio where its gradle build successful with compile time errors? Nooooo!!!

I have already tried:

- Clean Rebuild project
- Restart IDE
- Delete build folder
- Delete .gradle folder
- Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: You haven't tried `Invalided Cache -> Restart...`

Comment: Tried, i mention it here also.

Comment: strange, try cleaning it through command in terminal gradlew cleanBuildCache.

Comment: Can you delete  .idea folder and clean + Rebuild?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Finally i got error resolved as below answer..

Comment: @sagar great, I solved by deleting the folder .idea (AS 3.1.3). I had deleted any cache (_$HOME/.gradle/cache_, _.gradle/cache_, _cleanBuildCache_, _invalidate cache / restart_ ) and none of these worked. thank u ;-)

Comment: @VincenzoPetronio great! good to know. I will put it as answer so that others can benefit and don't have to read through comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me:

1. Delete `.idea` folder
2. clean + Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked.

- Delete build folder
- Close project
- Import project from `File>New>Import Project` (**Instead of opening**)

Now I got all errors as expected.